# Ошибка CORS в POST запросе

Tags: javascript, api, post

С сегодняшнего дня post запрос перестал работать. В коде ничего не менял. api сайта с которым я работаю - https://shikimori.one/oauth. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все данные которые я отправляю тоже верны. Ниже напишу код

```
function getauth(){
    var Atoken = document.getElementById('auth').value;
    const authURL = 'https://shikimori.one/oauth/token'
    function sendAuth(method, url, authData = null){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open(method, url)
            xhr.responseType = 'json'
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.onload = () => {
                if(xhr.status >= 400){
                    alert('Упс... чет не так пошло, сейчас попробую получить новый токен')
                    refresh()
                } else {
                    resolve(xhr.response)
                }
            }
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(authData))
        })
    }
    const authData = {
    "User-Agent": 's’app',
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    client_id: "yqz2V-vKKE3pNJz2F7s2YYANGgRYfXYh9TlfxlMWcJ4",
    client_secret: "sdQSoHuY4rXrEojlVAY6d6cDdM_QbrDR6wMgcaQoVmE",
    code: Atoken,
    redirect_uri: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
    }
    sendAuth('POST', authURL, authData)
    .then (function (data){
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh', JSON.stringify(data.refresh_token));
        localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(data.access_token));
        var AcToken = localStorage.getItem('auth');
        var parseAcToken = JSON.parse(AcToken);
    }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что вчера у shikimori было обновление с rails 5 до rails 6.
Во время обновления были удалены настройки CORS. Сейчас они восстановлены, все работает. Ниже будет скрин работы POST запроса.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install cors
```

```js
const cors = require("cors");

// middlewares
app.use(cors());

// routes
...
```

Comment: это куда прописать?)

Comment: Должно быт написано на стороне сервера